# MEL Script Button deletes object if it exists

Tags: object, button, maya, mel

My MEL knowledge isn't great and I have created a small script that duplicates your object and brings it next to your main one. I want to make it like when you click the MEL button the object appears but when you click it again the object gets deleted (if exists). Any help would be great as I'm almost at the point where I'm gonna start hitting my head on the wall.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of code that will delete an object if its found:

```
if (objExists("YOUR_OBJECT_NAME_HERE"))
{
delete("YOUR_OBJECT_NAME_HERE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create our test object. It's a `nurbsSphere1`:

```
sphere -p 0 0 0 -ax 0 1 0 -ssw 0 -esw 360 -r 1 -d 3;
```

`if...else` statement in MEL is quite simple. Use the following code to select and delete a `nurbsSphere1` if it exists in your scene:

```
if(`objExists nurbsSphere1`) {
    select nurbsSphere1;
    delete nurbsSphere1;
} else {
    warning("No NURBS Sphere exists");
}
```

To execute just several lines of MEL code (not all) in Script Editor, select all the lines you need and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> on a keyboard for execution.